# Grammar in proverbs

Tags: proverbs

"Tomorrow come never"  I have seen it in a dictionary of English idioms. Not "never comes", not "will never come".

I am confused. "Tomorrow come never" - is it correct?

Comment: You've got a false premise in your question. The proverb is **not** "tomorrow come never", it is "[tomorrow never comes](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0076832/)".  In short: "tomorrow come never" *is* ungrammatical, but that's irrelevant, because *no one says it*. And yes, "tomorrow will never come" is also perfectly fine.

Comment: On re-reading your question more carefully: can your provide a link to the dictionary of idioms you where you found "*tomorrow come never*"? Or, if it's hardcopy, a photograph of the entry? I can't imagine a legitimate guide including this phrase, but perhaps it lists it in an unexpected context.

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: @Dan Bron: *"tomorrow come never"* was indeed a 19th-century English "saying" (see my answer). I am baffled as to how to interpret the grammar. I suppose the verb could be subjunctive, but that doesn't really make sense to me. Some sources spell it *"tomorrow-come-never"*, which I expect shows they were also baffled by the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, it should be *"tomorrow comes never"* or *"tomorrow never comes."* However, apparently traditional English sayings need not be grammatical.

The explanation of this one, from the [1817 book](http://books.google.com/books?id=Fh9JAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22tomorrow+come+never%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Pdb7U7LfOa7ksAS_lIHIDQ&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22tomorrow%20come%20never%22&f=false) *An Attempt at a Glossary of Some Words Used in Cheshire:*

> Tomorrow come never
>   When two Sundays come together.
>
> To a person less given to the fulfilling than the making of promises, these words are often repeated by way of quip, when he engages to do something.

This is really a very obscure English saying, and I'm not sure if anybody uses it nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Tomorrow is the subject which is singular. The verb form 'come' is for a plural subject.